# Bordas em cada parte do menu

Tags: html, css

Opa, estou criando um site usando html + css, estava fazendo um menu porém ficou meio bugada a parte da "borda" dele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Marquei em vermelho aonde ficou faltando as barrinhas azuis.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BurnSec</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="https://github.com/burnsecurity"><img src="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/settings.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li id="options">
        <a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">PenTest</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
    </li>
    <li id="options">
        <a href="#">Cursos</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
            <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li id="options">
        <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="paginas/hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/outros.html">Outros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/contato.html">Contato</a>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/sobre.html">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul> 
<center><h1>BurnSec</h1></center>
<script src="prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<script src="js/particles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background-image:url('index1.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#000;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    background: black;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0000CD;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #0000CD;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 205, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#settings a {
    padding: 18px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #00008B;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#search_button {
    border: 0 none;
    background: white url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/C/y/X/u/K/search-icon-md.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}
#options>a {
    background-image: url(triangle.png);
    background-position: 85% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 42px;
}
.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1{
    color: #E6E6FA;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family: Awesome;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}
h2{
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu CSS tá meio confuso mas o principal erro na sua marcação é que você está repetindo `id`'s, o que é incorreto no HTML. Um id deve ser único na página. No caso, você está repetindo `id="options"` em mais de uma `<li>`.

Para corrigir isso, troque por `class="options"` no HTML e no CSS troque onde tiver `#options` por `.options`. Isso irá aplicar as bordas à esquerda em todos os itens do menu. E para adicionar uma borda à direita dos elementos que você quer, crie uma classe própria pra isso e adicione apenas nos elementos que não tiverem a borda à direita:

```
.borda-direita{
   border-right: 1px solid #0000CD;
}
```

Por exemplo, aplique na `li` onde tem o texto "Cursos" e na última `li` onde tem o texto "Sobre":

```
                   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
<li class="options borda-direita">
  <a href="#">Cursos</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
      <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Seu código ficará assim (como não é responsivo, execute o código abaixo em tela cheia):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 body {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  background-image:url('index1.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color:#000;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    background: black;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #0000CD;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #0000CD;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 205, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#settings a {
    padding: 18px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #00008B;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
#search_button {
    border: 0 none;
    background: white url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/n/C/y/X/u/K/search-icon-md.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}
.options>a {
    background-image: url(triangle.png);
    background-position: 85% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 42px;
}
.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
.options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1{
    color: #E6E6FA;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family: Awesome;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}
h2{
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.borda-direita{
   border-right: 1px solid #0000CD;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
        <a href="https://github.com/burnsecurity"><img src="https://designmodo.com/demo/dropdown-menu-search/settings.png" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Serviços</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">PenTest</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/ferramentas.html">Ferramentas</a>
    </li>
<li class="options borda-direita">
  <a href="#">Cursos</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="certificados.html">Premium</a></li>
      <li><a href="gratuitos.html">Gratuitos</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li class="options">
        <a href="#">Tutoriais</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="paginas/hacking.html">Hacking</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/programacao.html">Programação</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/pentest.html">PenTest</a></li>
            <li><a href="paginas/outros.html">Outros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="paginas/contato.html">Contato</a>
    <li class="borda-direita">
        <a href="paginas/sobre.html">Sobre</a>
    </li>
</ul> 
<center><h1>BurnSec</h1></center>
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode editar a seguinte classe no seu caso, adicionando o tamanho da borda, seguido do estilo junto com a cor:

```
#options a{
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Já que suas margens estão todas a esquerda, para adicionar uma margem a direita somente ao ultimo filho do menu, você pode acrescentar ao seu código:

```
.nav li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Veja esse [PEN](https://codepen.io/edsonfilho10/pen/qzNjPX)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, ficou perfeito! abraços <3